# Scaling drawable resources

Tags: java, android, drawable

I have just done some image editing of my application so now i want to make it fit for  every device by scaling them into different sizes.
I have found a site where i put an image then it scales it to different screen densities so when i put in into my project it does not adapt to the screen.

Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundapp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSwitch"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:src="@drawable/poweroffline"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/FlashBlinkButton"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/blinkoffline"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSwitch"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/AlarmButton"
        android:src="@drawable/alarmoffline"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/FlashBlinkButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: It automatically goes for the mdpi folder.

Comment: can you explain a little bit mor of your problemr? It´s not absolutely clear where you stuck...

Comment: if i convert my image into drawable it automatically goes for the lower one even if i have 6 inch screen.

Comment: do have have the default drawable folder in your project structure? Did you put the images also inside this?

Comment: yes,but the thing is that no matter what i put,it just goes for the mdpi.

Comment: sorry for this questions, but I try to find it out. And why do you think it takes mdpi? 1. In your xml I see you have set a fixed size to the imageViews. Do you have set different dp for different screen sizes via the dimen xml? And 2. the mdpi is like default drawables maybe, I can´t remember exactly but I had the same problem in the past and I think removing the drawables from the default drawable folder fixed it. It´s worth a try, just cut the images from this folder and put it in another one on your pc so you can put them back if it not helps....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs tried but without luck :(

Comment: and what about the different dp for your image views? have made them in dimen.xml?

Comment: default screen margins is set to 16dp.

Comment: I mean layout_width and layout_height....

Comment: you have to add different sizes into the dimen.xml and reference the size in your imageViews....

Comment: if i set it right on a device,on another device the images are not quite right in their place.

Answer (score 0):

You can try set **android:scaleType**

For example :

```
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/FlashBlinkButton"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:src="@drawable/blinkoffline"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnSwitch"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

You can see different variations in this docs
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: I need a correlation between my background layout and the buttons.When i put it on another device it scales just the buttons because i made them relative to each other but not the background.